# Eliminate count that comes from the left join and not the sales table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The following query returns the sales per month, regardless if the month is 0. If I group `@sales` by month then it will return one sale in February and 2 sales in April. This is correct.

Since this will be used as a running total later on, I'll need a count for all months, even if 0. So I do a left join with table 1@months` so that every month is returned regardless of the count.

```
declare @sales table
(
    salesdate date
)
insert into @sales
select '2/20/2021' union
select '4/15/2021' union
select '4/20/2021'

/* This result is correct: will return two rows: one sale in February and 2 sales in April */
select month(salesdate) as monthnumber, count(*) 'salesTotal' from 
@sales
group by month(salesdate)
order by month(salesdate)




declare @months table 
(
    monthnumber int,
    monthname varchar(10)
)
insert into @months
select 1, 'January' union
select 2, 'February' union
select 3, 'March' union
select 4, 'April' union
select 5, 'May'


select m.monthname, m.monthnumber, count(*)
from @months m left join @sales s on
m.monthnumber = month(salesdate)
group by m.monthname, m.monthnumber
```

The last query returns the following result:

```
monthname        monthnumber        TotalSales
January          1                  1
February         2                  1    //This is correct
March            3                  1
April            4                  2    //This is correct
May              5                  1
```

The problem with this result is that the left join will always return a positive count(*) even if the actual sales count is 0.

How can I exclude the row count if there aren't any sales for the month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `COUNT(*)`, you need an aggregation that will differentiate between non-NULL and NULL values from @sales in the event that the LEFT JOIN does not match because there's no sales in a given month. Try something like this:

```
select m.monthname, m.monthnumber, sum(case when s.salesdate is not null then 1 else 0 end)
from @months m 
left join @sales s 
    on m.monthnumber = month(salesdate)
group by m.monthname, m.monthnumber
```

The `SUM()` in conjunction with the `CASE` statement will only tally sales that match, as opposed to always counting the single NULL row that is the result of the LEFT JOIN missing.

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked well.

Answer (score 0):

**A much simpler solution than @pwang (which is very useful in some situations), is to just use `COUNT` on a column.**

`COUNT` will only count non-null values, so we can just specify a column from the `sales` table, which will be null if there is no join result:

```sql
select
   m.monthname,
   m.monthnumber,
   count(salesdate)
from @months m 
left join @sales s 
    on m.monthnumber = month(salesdate)
group by m.monthname, m.monthnumber
```

**The column must be a `NOT NULL` column, otherwise results may be incorrect.**